# When the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}}{n^p-1}$ converges

Tags: calculus

I need to check for which $p$ values the series below converges:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}}{n^p-1}$$

I used comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and got that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n^p-1}\leq\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n^p}n^2=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {\left(\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}\right)n^{2-p}}$$

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I can't figure out why you multiplied with $n^2$. You're throwing away quite a lot with that.

Comment: I was trying to put bounds to it. I can see that it has no upper bounds, but I have problem with setting lower bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a series with positive terms if $p>0$, you can compare with an *equivalent* series:
$$\sin\dfrac\pi n\sim_\infty\frac\pi n,\quad n^p-1\sim_\infty n^p,\quad \text{hence}\quad\frac{\sin^2\dfrac\pi n}{n^p-1}\sim_\infty\frac{\pi^2}{n^2n^p}=\frac{\pi^2}{n^{p+2}},$$
which converges if and only if $p+2>1$, i.e. $p>0$, since we've supposed $p>0$.

If $ p<0$, $n^p-1\sim\infty -1$, and it is a series with negative terms; its general term is equivalent to $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{n^2}$, which converges.

Comment: Nice trick. But that is not rigorous, is it?

Comment: How do I find lower bound?

Comment: It is perfectly rigourous. I rely on a theorem about equivalence which is proved, and the notion of equivalence has a precise definition in Asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Lower bound of what?

Comment: For $p<0$ . I found answer in a book, that series converge for $p>-1$

Comment: That very series? By itself, the series $\sin^2\dfrac\pi n$ converges, and $1-2^{-p}\le\lvert n^{-p}-1\rvert<1$ for $p>0$, so the general term is between $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{n^2}$ and $-\dfrac{\pi^2}{(1-2^{-p})n^2}$.